# Firebase is 'undefined'

Tags: javascript, firebase

I just decided to try the new firebase SDK for JavaScript but I keep getting this error in my console, any help or advice is appreciated

Code:

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.21.1/firebase-app.js"></script>

<!-- TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
    https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries -->
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.21.1/firebase-analytics.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.21.1/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
<!--<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.21.1/firebase-storage.js"></script>  -->

<script>
  // Your web app's Firebase configuration
  // For Firebase JS SDK v7.20.0 and later, measurementId is optional
  var firebaseConfig = {
    <!-- Not necessary-->
  };

  // Initialize Firebase
  firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
  firebase.analytics();
  //var db = app.firestore();
</script>

<script>
  function sendMessageToServer(msg) {
    var object = {
      value: msg
    };


    firebase.firestore().collection("Deskop").doc().set(object)
      .then(function() {
        adder.print("Data saved successfully");
      })
      .catch(function(err) {
        adder.print("Error writing document: " + err);
      });
  }
</script>
```

Error:

```
SCRIPT5009: 'firebase' is undefined
fire.html (34,5)
```

I have tried everything and made sure I followed the instruction in the firebase console but still the same error

Comment: Is `firebase- app.js` a typo? The other issue is that your code may be running before the scripts have finished loading.

Comment: `<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.21.1/firebase- app.js"></script>` should be a 404 as there is no script at that URL.

Comment: try adding defer load for all of the firebase scripts

Comment: I have tried that but the same thing still happened

Answer (score 0):

I have ran into similar problem the other day. Here is the solution I have found:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Application 2020</title>
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="../static/favicon.ico" />
    <link href="../static/css/site.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="container" id="container"></div>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.21.1/firebase-app.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.21.1/firebase-auth.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.21.1/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
    <script defer type="module" src="./App.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Load the scripts at the end, defer you starter js.
Then from there: `firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);`

Comment: I have tried this still not working any other suggestion

Comment: `npm init`; `npm i http-server --save`; `"scripts": { "start": "http-server -o --cors" }` in `package.json` ? Have you tried that? Also this was the only workaround that worked for me, with a defer a module js file starting like so: `export default (() => { /* firebase init here */ })();`